# Modify url path generated by serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there an easy way to modify the hyperlink generated by `serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField`? Specifically, I want to append `/download` to the url path.

```
> class AbcSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
>     url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="api:v1:abc-detail")
>     url_download = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="api:v1:abc-detail") #append /download to this url
> 
> class Meta:
>     model = abc
>     fields = ('url', 'url_download')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the view to the view that includes download in the url

or

Subclass HyperlinkedIdentityField and override get_url to include /download

```
class HyperlinkedDownloadIdentityField(HyperlinkedIdentityField):
      def get_url(self, *args):
             url = super().get_url(*args)
             return url+"/download"
```

and the serializer

```
...
url_download = HyperlinkedDownloadIdentityField(view_name="api:v1:abc-detail")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!